# How to put an image "in the same line" as another

Tags: html, css

I'm doing this exercise to study, the goal is:
I have 3 balls and 3 squares, I want to put the 3 balls in the squares using CSS. But here's the problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Fygq.png

I'm trying to use `padding-top: -??px;` to put it there, but seems like the image cant go to the same "line" as the other one is.

Here is the code:

```css
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="imagem1">
            <img src="bola 1.png">
        </div>
        <div class="imagem2">
            <img src="bola 2.png">
        </div>
        <div class="imagem3">
            <img src="bola 3.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>


.main {
  background-image: url('fundo.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.imagem1 {
  padding-left: 283px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.imagem2 {
  padding-left: 530px;
  padding-top: 110px;
}

.imagem3 {
  padding-left: 1000px;
  padding-top: -150px;
}
```

Comment: Please post some HTML. It's impossible to be confident in your problem without it. See [ask].

Comment: This is not possible to answer with out the HTML you are trying to style. Looking at your image my first thought would be that you need to use absolute positioning ( for two objects to occupy same location. Alternatively, the HTML would need for the square element to contain the circle element. Please provide html and we can give an answer

Comment: Although I have provided an answer, I do have to say it is a shot in the dark. I agree with isherwood and DeanO'Brien that HTML is required to provide a quality answer, rather than a random possible solution.

Comment: Now that the HTML is posted, it looks like what you want is to position the images, or actually the `<div>` elements that contain the images, in arbitrary positions around the wrapper element (according to the boxes in the bigger image). Am I understanding right?

Comment: yeah its that, what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

So here is the thing. **You should not be using padding to align items horizontally.**

A simple way is to use `inline-block`. Please check out how easy it is in the example below. You also need to set the `width` and potentially the `height` value of your images to be the same in the img tag. You can also use flex/flexbox [here is an explaination](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) if you do not want like this solution for some reason.

I want to emphasize that this is a generic solution, it may fix your problem, but it is best you provide HTML code for a more specific solution to your problem.

***SOLUTION SIMPLIFIED AFTER COMMENT***

```css
#container {
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  /* Setting the width may not be required in your case */
  width: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Notice the images have a set width -->
<div id="container">

  <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fpbs.twimg.com%2Fmedia%2FCYjenPGUoAAnp2t.jpg&f=1&nofb=1" width="200">

  <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fpbs.twimg.com%2Fmedia%2FCYjenPGUoAAnp2t.jpg&f=1&nofb=1" width="200">

  <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fpbs.twimg.com%2Fmedia%2FCYjenPGUoAAnp2t.jpg&f=1&nofb=1" width="200">

</div>
```

Comment: Images are inline by default. What makes you think that's the problem here, and why do you assume that the images are in divs?

Comment: @isherwood You do have a valid point.

Comment: I appreciate the desire to help, but darts in the dark sorta encourage poor questions.

Comment: @isherwood Hmm yeah, I kinda over-prioritize helping rather than  making further queries or making sure the website's norms are enforced. With 50k reputation, you have seen so many questions, you probably know better. I will leave it up for now, but will reinforce the need for the HTML code to be provided.

Answer (score 0):

you can use inline-block!

`#images {display: inline-block};`

Comment: thank you but, its not working.....